# Testing multiple usequeries in one component only considers one query

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-query

I am using React Query along with json-server to mock my API. I am trying to test my Home page which has a list of todos and one pined todo. The mock api will return 9 todos and 1 pined todo when calling these two queries. I am using msw to mock the api calls. I am trying to test that the Home page will render 10 todos (9 todos and 1 pined todo). However, the problem is that one query will be called which is the last to listen to the server. I tested on one query alone and it works so the React Query setup with React Testing Library is fine. I am not sure how to make sure that both queries are called before I render the component. I am not sure if I am using the right approach to test this. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my component code

```
export const HomeToDosList = () => {
    const { data: todos, isLoading: isLoadingToDos } = useTodos(page);
    const { data: pinedToDos, isLoading: isLoadingPined } = usePinedTodos();
  
    if (isLoadingToDos) {
      return <div>loading ...</div>;
    }
  
    if (isLoadingPined) {
      return <div>loading ...</div>;
    }
    return (
        <div>
          <ToDoItem initiative={pinedToDo.result} />
          {todos.result.map((todo: ToDo) => (
            <Fragment key={todo.id}>
              <ToDoItem todo={todo} />
            </Fragment>
          ))}
        </div>
    );
  };
```

Here is my test code

```
beforeAll(() => {
  getAllToDos.listen();
  getPinedToDos.listen();
});

afterEach(() => {
  getPinedToDos.resetHandlers();
  getAllToDos.resetHandlers();
});

afterAll(() => {
  getPinedToDos.close();
  getAllToDos.close();
});

describe('Home TODOS', () => {
  test('should render 10 todos', async () => {
    render(<HomeToDosList />);
    const todos = await screen.findAllByTestId('todo-card');
    expect(todos.length).toBe(10);
  });
});
```